# Retrieve header-files in conan

Tags: conan

Reading through the conan-docs, i can find very little information about header-files.
The focus seems to be entirely on retrieving built shared or static libraries.
For development, i obviously need header-files of the packages that i use.
One solution i came up with, was the following (in conanfile.txt)

```
[imports]
include, *.h -> ./include
```

which copies the .h files from my dependencies into my local include-folder.
Problem is of course that this does not make a distinction between the different packages, and just puts all the files into the include-folder, without subdirectories.
I can't really believe that this is the intended way of doing things.

How would i retrieve the header-files of my dependencies, while being able to place them in a reasonable path?

**edit**: I just read that it is possible to specify the package from which to copy inside the `[imports]` settings. This changes a lot, as it means that a reasonable directory-structure is possible. My question still remains though, if specifying `.h` files in the `[imports]` is the preferred way of retrieving header-files.

Comment: For most cases, copying the headers is not necessary. While developing packages are used from the Conan cache, not from local user folder, and that is done via the ``generators`` (there are a few for popular build systems, you can create your own generator as well). The ``imports`` functionality is mostly intended as a way to extract some files as dlls for final deployment (msi, deb package, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want every package to be copied to its own folder you have different alternatives:

- With the `deploy` generator, you don't need to specify at all the `imports`. Everything from all packages is copied locally. If you are not using generators (which is the recommended way to use packages) to use packages directly from the cache (also the recommended way), then, it is likely that you want to copy all packages locally. Use the `-g=deploy` in the command line or conanfile to do this.
- Use the `folder` specifier: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile_txt.html#imports

```
[imports]
include, *.h -> ./include @ folder=True
```

Comment: So do i see it right that letting conan copy header-files to the local directory is the recommended way? Via the `deploy`-command you mentioned? Because another way i could think of would be to specify include-paths of the IDE to incorporate the header-files directly from the conan-cache. That way dependencies and own source-code would be kept even more separate. Do you happen to know if something like this is possible?
**edit**: just saw your comment on my question, where you point in a similar direction.

Comment: No, using ``deploy`` is still not the recommended way to build, links and use Conan packages, but to use them directly from the Conan cache, via Conan ``generators``. This is what the generators do, provide information to the build systems and the IDEs, so they can locate what they need directly in the Conan cache, without needing multiple extra copies inside every project.

Comment: I assumed generators were just for the build-systems, your hint at them being also used for IDE-integrations is quite helpful! Now i just need to find, or hack together myself, a generator suitable for vscode :)

Comment: **note:** if anyone happens to end up here, i found [this](https://github.com/mkovalchik/conan-vscodepropertiesgen) little generator for vscode. You might either want to just use it in your project, or adapt it to your needs - it served as a great starting-point for me :)

Comment: Yeah, exactly, as a built-in example generator, there is the YouCompleteMe (ycm generaor) https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/ide/youcompleteme.html that is intended exclusively for vim to find the dependencies headers, etc.